# AngularJS google map infowindow

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I am using angular-google-map api http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api

The info window displays on the top of the marker. Is their a way to change it's position to right with the top aligned with the marker? I saw some infowindows fully custom with a custom position and a custom color but we never have the codes or how it is done. Do you have any exemples with the codes or a tutorial to show me? Thanks

**UPDATE:**

The Infobox instead of the infowindow can do the trick. But I did not manage to find a way to use the infobox with my angular-google-map ui. Can someone please help?

Comment: There is [InfoWindowOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions) available, you can change the `pixelOffset` or `position` property, so that your infowindow position can be changed.

Comment: I did not find a way to do what I want. I want to fully customize the map infowindow like on this website http://www.booking.com/city/nl/amsterdam.fr.html#map_opened
for exemple when you click on a marker with a building icon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside map object you can set inside window.options param pixelOffset

```
map: {
  control: {},
  ...
  window: {
   ...
    options: {
      visible: false,
      pixelOffset: {
        width: -1,
        height: -25
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I have asked the same question on their support page and got a valuable reply. You can find it here https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1434#issuecomment-130292587

Since infobox is included in the angular google maps library, all you need to do is provide options as follows

```
windowOptions:{
   boxClass: "YOUR CSS CLASS",
   boxStyle: { "YOUR STYLE" }
}
```

and then use it in your view like this

```
<ui-gmap-google-map>
<ui-gmap-window options="windowOptions"></ui-gmap-window>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Danscho/L789znLk/

Comment: I'm failing to fin where is this documented, but it works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to to applay the same effect on many windows ?

http://jsfiddle.net/crsex1sk/

Comment: @jlafforgue You should check the official doc at https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api Please check both **window** and **windows**. In window you pass an expression whereas on windows you pass the name of the property in the models array

Comment: That's exact thanks for information !
I tried to move my values ​​in the model but it does not work and I have an error in my console... Could be that I'm not using the right process ?
http://jsfiddle.net/jj4v9n8o/
`Unable to get gMarker from markersScope!`